# Is there a noetherification of locally noetherian schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm curious about the following:

> Is there a noetherification of locally noetherian schemes?

My motivation is the $1$-point compactification of locally compact hausdorff spaces. Of course schemes are very rigid, so I wouldn't expect it to exist as much as wonder if it's true. If it exists, it should probably have the property of universality with respect to maps into noetherian schemes.

Cheers